# How do I merge the values of two rows together in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am using trying to merge 2 rows together but cannot seem to find a way.

I have used geom_col() and there are two Nigeria rows. One is labelled "Nigeria" and other is "NIGERIA". I want to merge the values of "sum_gt" for these 2 rows together as a single row.

Here is my code:

```
plastics %>% 
select(country, year, grand_total) %>%
filter(country != "EMPTY") %>% 
drop_na(grand_total) %>%
group_by(country) %>% 
summarize(sum_gt = sum(grand_total)) %>%
arrange(desc(sum_gt)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(reorder(x = country, sum_gt), y = sum_gt, fill = country)) +
geom_col() +
coord_flip() +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

the dataset is from TidyTuesday and here is the URL:

plastics <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-01-26/plastics.csv')

Answer (score 1):

They must have the same name, if you want to sum them. There is also "ECUADOR" and "Ecuador" in your dataset. To be sure that you catch all the cases I suggest you do the following before you start your piping:

```
plastics$country<- tolower(plastics$country)
```

Comment: Alternatively, change `group_by(country)` to `group_by(country = tolower(country))`